# Smart-Table is it possible to filter on blur

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smart-table

In the AngularJs module Smart-Table is it possible to force st-search="column" to only trigger on blur?

Comment: As fabio stated below, using the [`ngModelOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) directive with updateOn set to blur is the way to go. It might be easy to simply add it to the input that your currently using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The st-input-event attribute will override the default to trigger on blur

```
<input st-search="firstName" st-input-event="blur" type="search"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom input like this:

```
<input st-search="firstName" placeholder="search for firstname" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" />
```

with [ng-model-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) you can setup alot of configuration and one of these is the `updateOn`, also you can use in a entire form!